# two where conditions in a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a table like below

> ```
> |date|dom|guid|pid|errors|QA|comm|
> |2010-03-22|xxxx.com|jsd3j234j|ab|Yes|xxxxxx|bad|
> |2010-03-22|xxxx.com|jsd3j234j|ab|No|xxxxxx||
> |2010-03-22|xxxx.com|jsd3j234j|if|Yes|xxxxxx|bad|
> |2010-03-22|xxxx.com|jsd3j234j|if|No|xxxxxx||
> |2010-03-22|xxxx.com|jsd3j234j|he|Yes|xxxxxx|bad|
> |2010-03-22|xxxx.com|jsd3j234j|he|No|xxxxxx||
> ```

I want to retrieve the total count of "dom" referred to each "QA" and also I need the count of "errors" detected by the "QA"

```
SELECT date, count(dom), QA 
  FROM reports 
  WHERE date="2010-03-22" 
  GROUP BY QA
```

> ```
> |2010-03-22|2|ab|
> |2010-03-22|2|if|
> |2010-03-22|2|he|
> ```

```
SELECT date, count(dom), count(errors), QA 
  FROM reports 
  WHERE errors="Yes" 
  GROUP BY QA
```

> ```
> |2010-03-22|1|ab|
> |2010-03-22|1|if|
> |2010-03-22|1|he|
> ```

I want to combine the above two queries, is it possible.

If I use the below query, I am not getting the desired result.

```
SELECT date, count(dom), QA, count(errors) 
  FROM reports 
  WHERE date="2010-03-22" 
    AND errors="Yes" 
  GROUP BY QA
```

I want the below output

> ```
> |2010-03-22|2|ab|1|
> |2010-03-22|2|if|1|
> |2010-03-22|2|he|1|
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with:

```
SELECT date, COUNT(dom), QA, COUNT(NULLIF(errors, 'No')) FROM reports WHERE date="2010-03-22" GROUP BY QA
```

To explain how this works: `COUNT` returns the number of non-null values. We can use this to our advantage by turning errors with `'No'` into `NULL`, so `COUNT`won't count them. We do this with the `NULLIF` function, which returns `NULL` if the first and second arguments are equal.

Comment: No, the field itself is not null, but when the field is 'No', NULLIF(errors, 'No') will return NULL. If you want to, I can make you an example to demonstrate how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `OR` in place of `AND`:

```
.... date="2010-03-22" OR errors="Yes" GROUP BY QA
```