# How to use more than one WHERE expression in a SELECT clause?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, loops

I have the following bit of code:

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM jos_vm_product_details WHERE global_variant_id = '$global_variant_id'";
$result = mysql_query($query);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$row['name'];
}
```

Is it possible to select the $row['name'] only where something is matched:

```
Select $row['name'] WHERE id = $id
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why don't you modify the SQL query to filter the results down to the specific `$id` you are after?

Comment: Can't you simply put `WHERE` condition inside query?

Comment: The sample code may be vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html), which is a very serious [security risk](http://bobby-tables.com/). To fix this hole, switch from the outdated mysql extension to [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) and use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/PDO.prepared-statements), passing values as parameters to the statement rather than interpolating them directly into the string. If you need a PDO tutorial, try ["Writing MySQL Scripts with PHP and PDO"](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/php-pdo.html). The site you save may just be your own.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: Combining multiple where conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985745/), [two where conditions in a mysql query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537526/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question, but you can limit that in the query to begin with:

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM jos_vm_product_details WHERE global_variant_id = '$global_variant_id' AND id = '$id'";
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Otherwise if you need to limit it in the fetch loop, use something like:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  if ($row['id'] == $id) {
    echo $row['name'];
  }
}
```

But this is better handled in the query's `WHERE` clause as in my first example.

Comment: If you are going to do it this way, so there should be only 1 result expected, then `if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { echo $row['name']; }` will work.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your SQL statement and append

```
AND id = '$id'
```

or, if you prefer, you can add a conditional statement within the `while` loop to skip to the next row if the id doesn't match (not recommended)

```
if ($row['id'] != $id) continue
```

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

```
$query  = "SELECT name FROM jos_vm_product_details WHERE global_variant_id = '$global_variant_id'"
```

Answer (score 0):

For the health of your application: never ever "filter" output in your application layer, your DB was designed to do all this stuff in the fastest and simplest way.

Do what Michael and Borodin said!